# How can a single matrix element be accessed in Matlab / Octave?

Tags: matlab, matrix, octave

Suppose I have:

```
>> X = magic(5)
X =

   17   24    1    8   15
   23    5    7   14   16
    4    6   13   20   22
   10   12   19   21    3
   11   18   25    2    9
```

How do I get i'th element from the second column?

I already figured that indices in (some?) collections in Octave are one-based, but I'm not sure if that holds for matrices, too.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

See the [index expressions](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Index-Expressions.html#Index-Expressions) section of the manual. To get the i'th element from second column:

```
X(i,2)      # element 'i' from column 2
X(1:end,2)  # the whole 2nd column
X(:,2)      # same thing but shorter
x(:, [2 3]) # whole 2nd and 3rd column
```

Note that Octave is a language where array elements are in [column-major order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order#Column-major_order).

Comment: @wvxvw Whitespace is irrelevant. Think of the indexing as passing arguments to a function, each argument being a matrix. [2 3] is a vector, 1:5 is also a vector (range), 1:end is also just a range it simply interprets `end` as the last one. You can do 1:2:end for every two, just as you can with simple ranges.

Comment: @wvxvw give it a try. You already have Octave installed. Does it return the same result?

Comment: @wvxvw It is intended. The `:` is only used for ranges and selecting whole rows and columns in Octave, it's all the same. About the nickname, I automatically get a notification when commenting on my answer so no need.